# Как узнать тип формата изображения java.awt.*

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage

У меня есть входной java.awt.image.BufferedImage.
Я так понимаю его как то можно преобразовать в поток и потом из него получить формат изображения.

Но вот такой метод

```
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(BufferedImage в формате потока);

Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);

while (imageReaders.hasNext()) {
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) imageReaders.next();
    System.out.printf("formatName: %s%n", reader.getFormatName());
}
```

кидает исключение java.util.NoSuchElementException

на строчке ImageReader reader = imageReaders.next();

если кто понимает как можно по другому извлечь формат изображения буду очень благодарен.

Comment: BufferedImage не содержит формата изображения, то есть, его никак не получить. А что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: ну вот я загрузил изображение по url и преобразовал его в bufferedimage как узнать формат?)

Comment: После преобразования в BufferedImage - никак) Информация о формате теряется, так тут уже чистые данные хранятся. Получить формат по юрл можно из других типов, не знаю как вы там грузите MultipartFile, скажем. Оттуда можно вытянуть формат файла или еще какие изощренные методы. ВОпрос отсается открым: Вам зачем? :)

Comment: да думал валидацию добавить)) просто клиент на фронте вставляет ссылку на изображение и она идет в сервис. и типа защиту что если это не изображение то ... Но я уже обнаружил что если это не изображение но BufferedImage после преобразования становиться null и все ясно.

Comment: Валидацию делайте по MultipartFile.getContentType(). И там либо MediaType.IMAGE_PNG либо MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG. Не знаю как в случае с попыткой преобразовать в картинку, но тут валидация завернет запрос еще до того, как файл начал передаваться, а не после того, он пришел на сервер целиком и теперь мы пытаемся сделать из него картинку